# Reduce logs of log4j in catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, catalina.out

I am using the [log4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for logging in my Java based [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) application and using version 1.2.14 (log4j-1.2.14.jar). The problem is that it creates more logs in the `catalina.out` log file, which are very micro level logs and not required for me. I am facing the problem of memory in my machine, and I want to reduce the logging of the log4j logger. Is there a way to reduce logs such that I can save my memory?

Comment: How is log4j currently configured in your application? Show us the config file, please

Comment: There is not any configuration, I have just used that jar as my API for logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a properties or a [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) configuration file will allow you to control log4j output as stated in the log4j manual.

An example of the properties file would be like this

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=**ERROR**, file
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\mylogging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Note the rootLogger parameter, as it controls how much information you get, whether you need only error messages or everything down to information messages.

In order to set it properly, look in *[Log4j Configuration Using Properties File](http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/sample-log4j-properties-file-configuration-1.html)* for extra information as you can also use it in the XML version (see *[Multiple Appenders Using XML File](http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-xml-configuration-multiple-appender.html)*). Tip: place it in src/ or in project root.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to look at CATALINA_HOME/conf folder for log4j.properties and raise the logging level to say, warn or error depending upon your needs

Comment: Still I am not getting the requested question's correct answer.

Comment: I am unable to comprehend your problem. Could you provide the file contents as requested by either Alfabravo or me in your question?